# How to call plugin path in JS?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using **wp-store-locator** plugin and I want to add plugin directory path to my JS.

```
html = "<li data-store-id='" + id + "'><div><p>" + storeImg + "<strong>" + store + "</strong><span class='wpsl-street'>" + address + "</span>" + address2 + city + " " + state + " " + zip + "</p>" + moreInfo + "<span><a href='plugin-urlpath/store-listings.php' class='more-details'>More details</a></span></div></li>";

return html;
```

How can I do that ? Plugin path is at the end of `html`.

I have tried like this :

```
var pluginURL = 'pluginpathhere';
```

But I don't want to this.Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [plugins_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url). Example usage:

```
<?php $url = plugins_url(); ?>
```

In your case:

```
html = '<li data-store-id="' + id + '"><div><p>' + storeImg + '<strong>' + store + '</strong><span class="wpsl-street">' + address + '</span>' + address2 + city + ' ' + state + ' ' + zip + '</p>' + moreInfo + '<span><a href="<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/store-listings.php" class="more-details">More details</a></span></div></li>';

return html;
```

Comment: But how can I implement this in my JS ?

Comment: `echo` the url into your JS variable.

Comment: how should I use `echo` in JS ?

Comment: Its not working .. It is giving me path like this **<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/store-listings.php**.

Answer (score 0):

Echo the variable into your javascript like this

```
echo "
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
   var pluginURL =  '" . plugins_url() . "/store-listings.php';
</script>
```